# loop returning inadequete records from database

Tags: asp.net

I have a list that is taking data from a database. It is always **leaving** one record that meets my database search query. when i change the database details to increase or decrease the records, it still leaves one record. out of say 8 records that meets a search criteria it returns 7, out of say 5 it returns 4

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*** Initial Catalog=***y;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***"))//connection string
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SubjectName FROM dbo.mySubjects WHERE SubjectClass = @theSubjectClass", con);//query string 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@theSubjectClass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myClass;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            //int t = 0;
            //count = count + 1; Tried adding a counter that gets the number of raws in the table that meet the search query and create a loop based on that but it produces an error of trying to read data where there is no data to read
            while ( count >= 0) {
                dr.Read();
                List <string> Subjects = new List<string>();
                Subjects.Add(dr.GetString(0));
                //t = 0;
                foreach (var course in Subjects)
                {
                    var a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    a.Attributes["class"] = "color-info";
                    var container = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    container.Attributes["class"] = "col-lg-4 col-sm-6";
                    var div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    div.Attributes["class"] = "card card-warning wow zoomInUp animation-delay-5";
                    var text = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    text.Attributes["class"] = "card-block text-center";
                    var p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
                    text.Controls.Add(p);
                    string manage = dr.GetValue(0) + " Videos";
                    var btn = new Button
                    {
                        Text = manage,
                        CssClass = "btn btn-warning"
                    };
                    btn.Click += new EventHandler(ExploreButtonClick);
                    text.Controls.Add(btn);
                    div.Controls.Add(text);
                    container.Controls.Add(div);
                    a.Controls.Add(container);
                    Row.Controls.Add(a);
                    count = count - 1;
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is incorrect. It should be:

```
using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        ....<your code here>
    }
}
```

Of course in this version you no longer need this `List <string> Subjects` collection and `foreach (var course in Subjects)` loop to repack it.

Comment: i used the above solution in a different scenario and it worked perfectly fine but in the above scenario the solution now produces half the expected results. let me debug some more